# display source directories from sbt task for current project as well as source directories of project it dependsOn

Tags: scala, sbt

```
sbt sourceDirectories
```

only displays source directories of current project, but doesn’t display source directories of projects that it depends using

```
dependsOn(ProjectRef)
```

Below is the simplified task.

```
lazy val showAllSourceDirs = taskKey[Unit]("show source directories of all projects")
showAllSourceDirs := {
  val projectRefs = loadedBuild.value.allProjectRefs.map(_._1)
  projectRefs foreach { projectRef =>

    /*
      Below line is giving IllegalArgumentException exception :-
             
      [error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find proxy for projectRef: sbt.ProjectRef in
      List(value projectRef, value $anonfun, method sbtdef$1, method $sbtdef, object $7fb70afe92bc9a6fedc3,
      package <empty>, package <root>) (currentOwner= method $sbtdef )
     */

    val sources = (projectRef / Compile / sourceDirectories).value
    sources.foreach( println )
  }
}
```

Link for simplified project to reproduce problem :-

https://github.com/moglideveloper/Example

---

Steps :

Go to **ApiSpec directory** from command line and run below command :-

```
sbt showAllSourceDirs
```

Expected output : print all source directories of Api and ApiSpec project

Actual output : throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you cannot do that, because sbt works with macros. What you can do here, is adding `sourceDirectories` of `Api` into `sourceDirectories` of `ApiSpec`. This means, that if you add the following into your sbt:

```
Compile / sourceDirectories ++= (apiModule / Compile / sourceDirectories).value
```

Then, when running:

```
sbt sourceDirectories
```

You get the output:

```
[info] * /workspace/games/Example/ApiSpec/src/main/scala-2.12
[info] * /workspace/games/Example/ApiSpec/src/main/scala
[info] * /workspace/games/Example/ApiSpec/src/main/java
[info] * /workspace/games/Example/ApiSpec/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main
[info] * /workspace/games/Example/Api/src/main/scala-2.12
[info] * /workspace/games/Example/Api/src/main/scala
[info] * /workspace/games/Example/Api/src/main/java
[info] * /workspace/games/Example/Api/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/main
```

There is one thing you need to notice - you are overriding the current sourceDirectories, so be sure you are not using it anywhere else.

Another note, is that you need to add this line on every dependency you have. So I am not sure how big is your project, and how feasible that is.

If you'd like to have a different task, you can do that, bur use the modules themselves, and not thru reflection, again due to macros.

```
lazy val showAllSourceDirs = taskKey[Unit]("show source directories of all projects")
showAllSourceDirs := {
  println((apiSpecProject / Compile / sourceDirectories).value)
  println((apiModule / Compile / sourceDirectories).value)
}
```

Comment: yes, for this specific requirement, we have two specific projects. one is Api and other is integration tests in seperate directory. APi is maintained by a contractor and is in a different repository. And ApiSpec is maintained by us. We don't want to give unnecesary acces of Spec to contractor.

Comment: @mogli So I am not sure I fully understand. If you don't want to provide access to the contractor, how do you want it to read the folder hierarchy? If it is able to access the project, it can read all of the content in it . Do you want to prevent that? In addition, just out of curiosity, why do you need the aggregated source directory? What are you doing with that?

Comment: sbt plugins needs to read some meta data from source directories